# Base 64 string to Audio File

Tags: swift, base64, avaudioplayer

I am having trouble turning a base64 string into an audio file to be used with AVAudio Player

Whenever I try and convert base64 to data it is coming back as nil. audioFile is the base64 string.

```
    let audioData = Data(base64Encoded: audioFile, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    let audioData2 = Data(base64Encoded: audioFile)
    let audioD = NSData(base64Encoded: audioFile, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    let dataDecoded  = NSData(base64Encoded: audioFile, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
```

I've tried all these but they keep giving back nil as the data.

Comment: audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData!)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?